# Do template functions of integer types lead to multiple compiled instances?

Tags: c++, templates

In the code below, does each instantiation of the template function lead to separate compiled object code? In other words, if I had lots of function calls like `foo<398>()` would this explode the size of the binary, or can the compiler do "something smart" in this case?

Sorry for a slightly vagueish question. Pointers to the appropriate docs welcome.

```
template <int N>
int foo()
{
   return N;
}
int main()
{
  int a = foo<1>();
  int b = foo<2>();
  std::cout << a << ", " << b << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `"can the compiler do "something smart" in this case"`. With optimization, I expect generated code to be identical to the one for `std::cout << 1 << ", " << 2 << std::endl;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within each translation unit, there is a magic *point of instantiation* for each template specialization, and each template specialization is instantiated at most *once* per translation unit.

There's still a very interesting problem of how *different* translation units link together (and indeed the linker needs to know how C++ works and deduplicate), but at least intra-TU there's only one version of the function.

(The instantiation point is when the second phase of the two-phase lookup happens. So you only get an error once (at instantiation time), not for every time you use the specialization.)

Comment: But would `foo<1>()` and `foo<2>()` count as two different specializations/instantiations?

Comment: @TobySharp: Those are two different specializations (because they have different template arguments). I was responding you having "lots of calls like `foo<398>()`; only *one* instance of `foo<398>` is created and then used repeatedly. Separate instances are created for separate specializations.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, every instantiation with a different number will generate new binary code. This is a modified version of your example that proves that both functions have different addresses.

```
int main()
{
    int (*p1)() = &foo<1>;
    int (*p2)() = &foo<3>;

    std::cout << (void*)(p1) << ", " << (void*)(p2) << std::endl;
}
```

Here is a live example: http://ideone.com/w5peQV

EDIT: Better example by @xaxxon http://godbolt.org/g/DYXtHs

DISCLAIMER: Your original example and other trivial examples like it ARE optimizable by the compiler, the function will probably be optimized away.
But if you take addresses of your functions, have more complex code or simply disable optimizations, it is not guaranteed that it will be optimized away and your compiler WILL generate code for each instantiation.

Comment: godbolt provides a more instructive example: https://godbolt.org/g/DYXtHs  Scroll down to line 45 of the generated code to see that two instantiations are present.

Comment: @xaxxon nice! I didn't know that website and I don't have a linux terminal available right now. thanks

Comment: Addressing the "something smart" question, compiled with -O2 I'd expect to see no functions generated at all (unless their address was taken).

Comment: Well, sure, when you **take the addresses** of template functions you get different addresses for different instances. That does **not** mean that simply calling them has to produce two separate instances.

Comment: @PeteBecker maybe on a trivial example like this one it is possible to optimize them away. In an everyday example though, one that for some reason requires an integral template parameter instead of a regular one, different instances will probably be created.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't really address the question. A compiler (and linker) can optimize identical object code of several template instantiations into a single copy. This is called *Identical COMDAT Folding* ([with Microsoft's compiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxwfs976.aspx)).

Comment: @IInspectable, is that guaranteed on every case? Can you provide a live example?

Comment: @imreal -- regardless of what you think real-world examples might do, your example does not address the question. Your example **requires** separate instantiations, hence, cannot be used to determine whether, in general, it is possible to not generate separate instantiations.

Comment: @imreal: Live examples? Just compile any source base using templates, and toggle the switch on and off. Observe the sizes of the generated binaries, and look around the image with tools like DUMPBIN. Another live example: Step into template code in Visual Studio. When ICF is at work you have to manually pick the specific instantiation from a list of possible candidates. When you see that dialog pop up, you know that there is a 1-to-many mapping between object code and source code.

Comment: @PeteBecker I am not used to make assumptions as to how code will be changed to, end up being used, optimizations or anything that is not guaranteed on the standard.

Comment: @imreal - the standard does not require separate instantiations. It requires that the addresses of different instantiations be different, but that's only meaningful **if you take the address** of two or more instantiations. If you don't take their addresses, you cannot tell whether they are in the same location, so the compiler is free to do pretty much anything it wants, as long as the resulting code works correctly. Formally, that's the "as if" rule: the compiler has to produce the result **as if** it had done what's formally required, but doesn't have to actually do what's required.

Comment: @PeteBecker Ok we agree, in the exact specific example provided by the OP it IS possible to optimize it. But I don't know how the real code looks like or what do his templates do, or which compiler/optimizations he uses, so I don't think it is wise to mislead him into assuming anything.

Comment: @imreal - but your answer **is** misleading, since it says that the compiler **can never** optimize these things away.

Comment: You still seem completely confused, how ICF works (and similar schemes). For ICF, the compiler will **always** generate object code for each instantiation. It's the linker that determines, whether the generated object code for several objects is identical, and merges them into a single copy (if otherwise possible). And sure, turning off optimizations turns off optimizations. That's not entirely surprising.

Comment: @IInspectable I think I've been very clear in that I know that it is POSSIBLE to optimize the original code. But I also provided an example that prevents that optimization from happening (even with -O3). So it is not an optimization that can be relied on. Maybe if you write a huge ugly comment in the code instructing other developers to not take the address of that function or change it in any way.

Comment: @IInspectable in clang -no-deduplication turns it off.   it can take a VERY long time.   I have a project that goes from a 5s link to 150s link by allowing deduplication in clang.  The binary increases by ~2.5% by making the link 30x worse.

Comment: You provided an example, where the optimization would have violated language rules. The optimizer has to stay within the limits of the as-if rule. There are many other ways that prevent the optimizer from doing anything to the code. None of that warrants an answer, that an optimization wouldn't be possible for general, complex code (as yours implies). Anyway, I voted on your proposed answer, and explained why *down* is the correct vote. There is no reason for me to repeat this.

Comment: @xaxxon: Clang produces larger binaries when deduplication is enabled? That doesn't sound right.

Comment: @IInspectable sorry, there were lots of negatives in my previous statement.   The project builds much slower and very slightly larger with deduplication turned on.  This particular project is VERY heavily templated.  Someone over on the official llvm irc channel helped me figure out what was going on.  Also, this is only the case with -O0.   Once a lot of the functions are inlined, it gets much better.   Of course -flto kills the linker time.